# How can I show whether the following function is Increasing, Decreasing, or Constant returns to scale?

Tags: microeconomics

I need to show whether or not the following function is increasing, decreasing, or constant returns to scale, but I can't figure out how to extract the *t* from it when it is put in the form $y(tX_1, tX_2)$.
$$
y = X_2\sin{\left(\frac{X_1}{X_2}-\pi \right)}
$$
Is there any other way of showing IRS, DRS, and CRS? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You have $$F(x_1,x_2)=x_2\sin\bigg(\frac{x_1}{x_2}-\pi\bigg).$$
If you multiply all factors by $t$ you get
$$F(tx_1,tx_2)=t x_2\sin\bigg(\frac{tx_1}{tx_2}-\pi\bigg).$$
Simplify the fraction and you are almost done.

Answer (score 0):

in the case of for example a production function, returns to scale mean the effect when all factors of production are multiplied by a certain constant, with what constant is the production level multiplied?
i) the same constant as the factors of production (constant returns to scale)
ii) a larger constant (increasing returns to scale)
iii) a smaller constant (decreasing returns to scale)
So the right approach is to simply fill in a constant (let's call it c) in your function.
cX2(sin((cX1/cX2)-pi)
and try to rewrite it to 
d(X2(sin((X1/X2)-pi))
where d is the constant with which y is multiplied as a consequence of multiplying X1 and X2 with c